# How to know a Salesforce table field is auto-calculated?

Tags: salesforce, simple-salesforce

Salesforce provides `CaseMilestone` table. Each time I call the API to get a same object, I noticed that `TimeRemainingInMins` field has a different value. So I guessed this field is auto-calculated each time I call the API.

Is there a way to know what fields in a table are auto-calculated ?

Note : I am using python simple-salesforce library.

Answer (score 0):

Case milestone is special because it's used as countdown to service level agreement (SLA) violation, drives some escalation rules. Depending on how admin configured the clock you may notice it stops for weekends, bank holidays or maybe count only Mon-Fri 9-17...

Out of the box other place that may have similar functionality is OpportunityHistory table. Don't remember exactly but it's used by SF for for duration reporting, how long oppty spent in each stage.

That's standard. For custom fields that change every time you read them despite nothing actually changing the record (lastmodifiedate staying same) - your admin could have created formula fields based on "NOW()" or "TODAY()", these would also recalculate every time you read them. You'd need some "describe" calls to get the field types and the formula itself.